# What is pagination in the context of Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am bit confused what pagination means in the context of Spring Data. Is it to do with how much data is retrieved per round trip to the data source? Please can someone explain this concept.

Comment: it's standard pagination (i.e. retrieve X records starting from Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's exactly what you do when you add a `LIMIT(rowcount, offset)` clause in your SQL statement.

This is mostly used when you want to display "pages" of data when the result of your query gets too big, hence the `Pagination` concept.